# Using CSS3 Transitions and keyframes in JQuery .css()

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I'm trying to get CSS3 transitions to work in JQuery .css()

Something simple like

```
.someDiv { opacity: 1; background: #fff; transition: width 2s; }
```

formats into

```
$( ".box" ).one( "click", function() {
$(this).css({ "opacity": "1", "background": "#fff", "transition": "width 2s" });
});
```

I know that much.
But how do you format CSS3 transitions that have nested keyframes to work with JQuery?

```
.fadeInDown {
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;  
 animation-name: fadeInDown;  }

@keyframes fadeInDown {

0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
     transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }

100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a CSS file for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't hold me up on any of this.**

It's not so simple. Consider the following:

> jQuery has a very nice built in $(selector).animate() function which allows for easy setup of these animations. However, jQuery's animate() does not support multiple keyframes

With that being said, you can include the [jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes) library which would assit you in achieving what you want.

Just using the code you provided, you would be able to introduce the animation via jQuery -given that you add `jQuery.Keyframes` - with something like this:

```js
$.keyframe.define([{
  name: 'animation-name',
  '0%': {
    'opacity': '0',
    'transform': 'translate3d(0, -100%, 0)'
  },
  '100%': {
    'opacity': '1',
    'transform': 'none'
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to add keyframes using jQuery, but you can add CSS to the `head` like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var keyframes = '.fadeInDown {' +
                     '-webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;' +
                     'animation-name: fadeInDown; }' +

                    '@keyframes fadeInDown {' +

                    '0% {' +
                        'opacity: 0;' +
                        '-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);' +
                        'transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);' +
                        '}' +

                    '100% {' +
                            'opacity: 1;' +
                            '-webkit-transform: none;' +
                            'transform: none;' +
                        '}' +
                    '}';
  $('<style type="text/css">' + keyframes + '</style>').appendTo($('head'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Much easier and 100% solution!